# How to identify adjectives or adverbs?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, semantic-analysis

I am quite novice to NLP....Is there any API or a way in which i could identify verb or adjective or adverbs from a sentence?
I need it in a project?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a [Part-of-speech Tagger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pos-tagging) (POSTagger). This identifies the role of every word in the sentence. Wikipedia has an [excellent list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits) of NLP toolkits, and they will almost all have POSTaggers.

If your material is normal written English the POSTaggers will do well. If it's very colloquial (e.g. on Text Messages) or very unusual (e.g jargon) it may do worse. Note that for specialized language (I do chemistry) you may also need a tokenizer to work out where the word tokens are.

You mention "sentiment analysis". This is a lot more work but will absolutely need a POSTagger in the system. You also mention semantic analysis - for this you may need semantic lexicons. But start with the POSTagger and practice with common sentences.

Comment: Thanks for ur help...rust I just read about Apache OpenNLP... i can also use this for performing the pos tagging and parsing... So i can use it..or is there any other good compare to this available ......

Comment: wikipedia link appears dead now :-/