# is there any algorithm for classifying questions types from the interrogative words?

Tags: java, nlp

Questions can mainly be categorized into the following
classes based on interrogative words: yes/no class (such as
“Does roy jones jr have three kids”), choice class (such as
“Which country is bigger, Canada or America”), quantity class
(such as “When was the first mechanical calculator made”),
enumeration class (such as “Name of three neighboring countries
of south Korea”), and description class (such as “What are
the ways of minimizing fan violence in sport”)

till now i am getting first word of the question using program

```
String firstWord = null;

if(string.contains(" ")){

   firstWord= string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" ")); 
}
```

so i need to know how can i get the word  after 'how' is adjective or adverb?

Comment: You probably won't run into too many problems if you just categorize it by the first word, if all questions are in that form.

Comment: It may not relevant to your question but it gives you a different view of solving your problem. If you are looking for a framework for survey/questionnaire engine which is developed on top of Java then you may need to look into [ this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687720/open-source-survey-questionnaire-engine-for-java).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have a good question but it needs some reworking - please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to revise your question! I would at least mention some of the research you've already done.

Comment: thanks for revising your question! maybe this question touching on POS-tagging can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229661/how-to-identify-adjectives-or-adverbs

Answer (score 1):

You could use a string search algorithm, e. g. [KMP-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). Or you could look for a database optimized for holding strings.